# Updating row by row after have to sort a set of data mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I I have a table `table1`  like this in MySQL Db without primary key:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| value   | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| my_date | date        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| my_time | time        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Is it possible, after to sort the table by my_date and my_time value, 
update id value start from a given value ?

For example from this set of value

```
+------+------------+----------+
| id   | my_date    | my_time  |
+------+------------+----------+
|    0 | 2018-03-01 | 09:02:00 |
|    0 | 2018-03-01 | 09:01:00 |
|    0 | 2018-03-01 | 09:00:00 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

I want to obtain

```
+------+------------+----------+
| id   | my_date    | my_time  |
+------+------------+----------+
|  100 | 2018-03-01 | 09:00:00 |
|  101 | 2018-03-01 | 09:01:00 |
|  102 | 2018-03-01 | 09:02:00 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

I have tried something like this without success:

```
try {
    int idFromToStart = 100; 
    String query = "SELECT IFNULL(id, 0) FROM table1 WHERE my_date > '2018-02-28' order by my_date, my_time";
    preparedStatement =con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);            
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println("query " + query);            
    if (rs.next()) {
        rs.updateLong(1, idFromToStart);
        System.out.println("rs.getLong(1)) "+rs.getLong(1)+ " idFromToStart "+idFromToStart);
        idFromToStart++;
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error db " + ex.getMessage() + " " + ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: try cast time column to int and then sort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808573/sql-order-string-as-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @rownum = 99;
UPDATE tbl1
SET tbl1.id = @rownum:=@rownum+1
ORDER BY my_time
```

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34699f/1

Comment: @famedoro Come on, this SQL code should solve your problem. Wrapping up a simple `SET` and `UPDATE` in Java doesn't sound like a serious issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, so is it possible to use variables like @rownum in a `set` and `update` in java? Now I try

Comment: @famedoro Yeah, it should be possible. For example, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949908/using-a-mysql-variable-in-java-for-a-ranking-query

Comment: @famedoro Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't break anything by deleting rows in that table, move it all into a temporary table, truncate the current one, set `id` to auto increment and do the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (`value`, my_date, my_time)
SELECT `value`, my_date, my_time
FROM myTmpTable
ORDER BY my_date, my_time ASC;
```

Comment: I prefer do not use a temp table, because I have a lot of data

Comment: Use a temporary table of the type "memory" or "MyISAM" to increase speed. If both are not an option, is any combination of column values unique? If yes, it would be possible via a window-function. If not, you only have the option of using a temporary table or a really slow procedure with loops.